# Installing modules to Node.js on Android

Tags: android, node.js, sqlite, android-ndk, npm

I have successfully built Node.js for Android device using NDK.
I need to include several Node.js modules (Socket.io, express, SQLite3) for my application.

I've checked the Debian kit approach, it requires a rooted Android device, but I think it will be quite troublesome for the ordinary users to root the device before using my application.

I am trying to include these modules as core modules when building Node.js following these instructions: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Building-for-Android
However, I am not sure what exactly I have to include. Do I need to include all those dependencies?

Moreover, can I install a module programmatically using npm API: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/api/npm.html
It seems that I need to use npm to install npm module before I can use npm API.
It would be greatly appreciated if you kindly give me a clue. Thank you so much.